# Possibly for slow Client to Dupe

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

Im running a private server and so my friends and I are on and then i got  a message that one of the players was trying to break faster than possible from NCP.When when i checked on  another plugin called grieflog and Easylog it said that the player mined iron ore in the same spot in a 2 sec time frame 5 times.I banned him because of duping but he said that his computer is slow and he had to mine two times to get the ore.My computer is brand new with AMD FX 4.0 GHz and a bit more than 1G located with a internet connection of 4 megabits of upload speed and 40 megabits of download.

So did he dupe the ore or is it the computers fault?

Comment: It's probably not his computers fault, but rather his connection's fault.  It sounds like he's experiencing block lag.

Comment: Do you not trust your friend?

Comment: @TZHX sometimes i dont trust him

Comment: @Mbraedley well it only happens when he mines ores i havent seen a dupe report for mining cobblestone or stone

Comment: I have no experience with logging but it might be possible the dupe logging is only set on ores and other more valuable material then dirt and stone.

Comment: so your saying he has a hacked client or what?

Answer (score 2):

NoCheatPlus is unreliable, usually just being triggered by network lag. You should not use it as the sole reason to ban somebody, although you can use it to bring things to your attention to investigate further. Most global ban lists advise against NCP, and will refuse to accept it as evidence.

I am unaware of any way you could "dupe" an ore by mining it twice. On the other hand, it is very common for connection latency to cause a block to appear twice. They don't get two of the ore or any advantage, it's just really annoying for them.

The specs of your own computer have nothing to do with this; it's all about the connection between the server and the player you have banned.

I would personally advise trusting the player, NCP is pretty well known for bringing up a lot of false positives for laggy players and he hasn't actually duped the ore from mining it multiple times.

Comment: i didnt solely ban the player from NCP ncp gave me a warning i checked it out with GriefLog then i decide to ban him because he made a full iron armor set then but %75 of all the iron he mine was already mined like what i stated above

Comment: You said " the player mined iron ore in the same spot in a 2 sec time frame 5 times." That is 10 iron ore. There is nothing about him "cheating" 18 pieces of ore.

Comment: yes but he duped mine more iron i just didint say that